# How to write Interceptor for SlingClient

Tags: java, interceptor, sling

I need to write interceptor for SlingClient. I have very little idea about interceptors. 
My problem statement is, that I need to catch all the request which my slingclient is making, and then i need to modify those requests. And i have multiple clients which are extending from SlingClient. So any of the client is making any request alongwith some parameter, then i want to catch that parameter, and change it as per my requirement.
Please tell me how can I achieve that.

Comment: What is `SlingClient`?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to implement a `javax.servlet.Filter` as seen here [Cq5.5 applying a servlet filter to a specific path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862319/cq5-5-applying-a-servlet-filter-to-a-specific-path).

Comment: no, filter is not required. I need to work on interceptors.

Comment: But with a `Filter`, you can intercept the `SlingHttpServletRequest`.

Comment: Yes, thanks. but i dont have servlets which needs to be intercepted

Comment: Than you have to elaborate more on what you are actually doing. Do you need to intercept the requests in a servlet container or in you client application?