# How to add robots.txt file in AEM/CQ?

Tags: aem, aem-6

How to add the robots.txt file to an AEM server to provide rules for Web Crawlers in AEM?

Answer (score 1):

Most you will refer to [This Link](http://www.wemblog.com/2013/06/how-to-implement-robotstxt-sitemapxml.html)
To implement this.

Although it may seem to serve the purpose you will notice one thing that could be a little "not right".

**Adding a robots.txt file directly in crxde causes the creation of a node of type nt:file in root level.**

So when you hit http://localhost:4502/robots.txt instead of you displaying on the screen/browser the file downloads.

This is because of the **Default GET servlet**. The servlet identifies that the node type is nt:file and sends response with the content type as

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=robots.txt
```

To overcome this implement the filter as follows. By doing this you will skip call to the Default GET Servlet of Sling and will be able to provide a content type of your own.

```
 package com.hds.exp.filters;

import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.sling.SlingFilter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;

@SlingFilter(order=1)
@Properties({
    @Property(name="service.pid", value="com.hds.exp.filters.RobotsFilter",propertyPrivate=false),
    @Property(name="service.description",value="Provides Robots.txt", propertyPrivate=false),
    @Property(name="service.vendor",value="DD Exp", propertyPrivate=false),
    @Property(name="pattern",value="/.*", propertyPrivate=false)    
})
public class RobotsFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter{

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // Unused
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest =(HttpServletRequest) request;
        if(httpServletRequest.getRequestURI().equals("/robots.txt"))
        {
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            writer.print("User-agent: *");
            writer.print("\n");
            writer.print("Disallow: /");
            writer.print("\n");
            writer.flush();
        }
        else
        {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        // Unused
    }

}
```

Comment: only problem i have with this approach is now that if statement is being evaluated for every single request. somehow I feel leaving it to your web server would be preferable.